# Connect to openldap using php (windows)

Tags: php, ldap, openldap

I installed openldap on my windows machine, and i would like to get access to the ldap server using php.

I installed ldapexplorer to check, and everything works fine, here's the config i use :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptyj2.png)

Here's my php code (simple version)

```
<?php

$server = "ldap://LESPAUL";
$port = "389";

$ds=ldap_connect($server); 
echo($ds);
```

The problem is that no matter what parameter i give to ldap_connect (even a wrong one) the result i get is : ressourceid #2

Thanks for your help

Comment: From the tutorial i read, i'm supposed to have $ds = 1; because in this case i can not bind to the server when i try to

Comment: I finally got it working, thanks a lot for your advice. I'll post the answer to my problem, maybe it could help someone

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple:
ldap_connect doesn't actually connect to the server, it just initialize parameters, so as long as ldap_connect doesn't return 'false', it's okay

you just have to use the next function (usually ldap_bind)